Understanding how transformTemplates work in Renovate
My goal is to get a better understanding how transformTemplates work, I looked at documentation and is unclear how to properly extract the version for the examples listed below.
I created a minimal reproduction with 3 testing examples:
Functional, PR created: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cilium/cilium/main/stable.txt
    "cilium": {
      "defaultRegistryUrlTemplate": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cilium/cilium/main/stable.txt",
      "format": "plain",
      "transformTemplates": [
        "{\"releases\": $.releases, \"homepage\": \"https://cilium.io\", \"sourceUrl\": \"https://github.com/cilium/cilium\"}"
      ]
    }

While functional, I do not understand how the version is extracted from $.releases.
invalid-value $.lts.full_version: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/canonical/ubuntu.com/main/releases.yaml
    "cluster": {
      "defaultRegistryUrlTemplate": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/canonical/ubuntu.com/main/releases.yaml",
      "format": "yaml",
      "transformTemplates": [
        "{\"releases\": [{\"version\": $.lts.full_version}], \"homepage\": \"https://ubuntu.com\", \"sourceUrl\": \"https://github.com/canonical/ubuntu.com\"}"
      ]
    }

Version to extract from, should also work with $string(lts.full_version):
lts:
  full_version: "24.04.1"

No warning $.status: https://helm.baltorepo.com/stable/debian/packages/helm/badge/latest.json
    "helm": {
      "defaultRegistryUrlTemplate": "https://helm.baltorepo.com/stable/debian/packages/helm/badge/latest.json",
      "transformTemplates": [
        "{\"releases\": [{\"version\": $.status}], \"homepage\": \"https://helm.sh\", \"sourceUrl\": \"https://helm.baltorepo.com/stable/debian/packages/helm/\"}"
      ]
    }

Version to extract from:
{"subject": "latest", "status": "3.16.3-1", "color": "blue", "cache": 600}

I'm not sure what is the proper way to troubleshoot or obtain the version for last two faulty transformTemplates, thank you for your suggestions.
